# Twig show n keys of array or all

Tags: php, twig, templating

I have an editor with a set of buttons, and I want to display only a set of buttons based on twig::render variables.
If I include all I want it to display are buttons available, if I include individual button keys I want to display only that ones.

```
echo TwigLoader::render('@ui/editor.html.twig'['toolbar'=>['all']]);
echo TwigLoader::render('@ui/editor.html.twig'['toolbar'=>['font','size']]);
```

For the template I'm using the following code:

```
{% set toolbar_tools = [
{'font':'<select class="ql-font"></select>'},
{'size':'<select class="ql-size"></select>'}] 
%}

<div id="button-container">
    <span class="ql-formats">
        {% for tool, key in toolbar_tools %}
             {{ tool.key|raw}}
        {% endfor %}
    </span>
</div>
```

I'm getting an empty container. 
Is this a good strategy or there are better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you`re looking for something like this:

```
{% set toolbar_tools = {
        'font':'<select class="ql-font"></select>',
        'size':'<select class="ql-size"></select>'
    } 
%}

<div id="button-container">
    <span class="ql-formats">
        {% if toolbar|length > 0 %}
            {% for t in toolbar %}          
                {% if t == 'all' %}
                    {# show all options #}
                    {% for tool in toolbar_tools %}
                        {{ tool|raw }}                   
                    {% endfor %}
                {% else %}
                    {# show defined options #}
                    {{ attribute(toolbar_tools, t)|raw }}
                {% endif  %}
                <br />
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Hope you will be fine with that.